# What content should be in my /etc/network/interfaces file in 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have a laptop connected to a router using a wire. Today, the wired connection stopped working for no apparent reason. When I try to ping the router, I get "`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`". I can connect via wireless (as I do now), but not using a wire.
In the network settings, I see "Cable unplugged". In an attempt to debug this error, I looked at my /etc/network/interfaces file, which contained only the following lines:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`ifconfig` gives different results; sometimes it just gives this:

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 70:5a:0f:d8:0a:f7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2678  bytes 200055 (200.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2678  bytes 200055 (200.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and sometimes there is another segment:

```
enp0s31f6:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.8.252  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 70:5a:0f:d8:0a:f7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000
```

Following some advice on the Internet, I added the following lines to the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and rebooted, but it did not help. I replaced them with this:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

but then, when I rebooted my laptop, it stuck during boot, so I removed them.

Rather than trial-and-error, I would be very happy to know, what is the *correct* content of /etc/network/interfaces in my system?

Comment: The file `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated in Ubuntu 17.10 and later in favor of Network Manager for desktop installations and netplan for servers. @Pilot6 answer is entirely correct. I suggest that you troubleshoot the driver for your ethernet.

Comment: @chili555 thanks. What do you mean by "troubleshoot the driver for your ethernet" - where do I start?

Comment: Please start a new question and include: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` It will show the driver in use. Then we'll check the log to see if the driver is stumbling and if we can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct content of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

It should be

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```